# How to change this db2 merge query?

Tags: sql, db2

can someone help me? i am trying to convert the following merge into another query and i am allowed only to use insert and update once:

```
MERGE INTO MYEMPLOYEE ME USING EMPLOYEE E ON ME.EMPNO = E.EMPNO 
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET ME.SALARY = CASE WHEN ME.SALARY > E.SALARY THEN ME.SALARY ELSE E.SALARY END 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
INSERT VALUES(E.EMPNO, E.FIRSTNME, E.MIDINIT, E.LASTNAME, E.WORKDEPT, E.PHONENO, E.HIREDATE, E.JOB, E.EDLEVEL, E.SEX, E.BIRTHDATE, E.SALARY, E.BONUS, E.COMM);
```

How can I achieve this? the above merge copies the data if not exists, and if it exists it checks for the salary and selects the higher one and copies that one.
how can I achieve the same thing by only using one insert and one update? Can someone give me hints, please?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ...why do you have this requirement?  Why isn't `MERGE` allowed?  You have the base of the `UPDATE` and `INSERT` statements already, essentially - what's got you stuck?  Note that you _must_ perform the operations in that order - update existing rows then insert new (although not as dangerous as some cases).  Why are you not reducing people's salaries?

Comment: It is a requirement from the university, so there must be some way to actually convert the query without using the merge. Or dont you think there is another way? The task was to select the higher salary if the employee exists already, and if it doesnt exist to copy the whole entry - this task was assigned from my university.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `MERGE` command is suppose to take into account multiple actions of `UPDATE`, `INSERT`, `DELETE`.  [MERGE statement explained](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/merge?lang=en)

If you cannot/unable to use `MERGE`, then you have to resort to doing each request individually.

```
UPDATE MYEMPLOYEE ME
  SET ME.SALARY = (
    SELECT CASE WHEN ME.SALARY > E.SALARY THEN ME.SALARY ELSE E.SALARY END 
    FROM EMPLOYEE E 
    WHERE ME.EMPNO = E.EMPNO
 )
 WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 
   FROM EMPLOYEE E 
   WHERE ME.EMPNO = E.EMPNO
 );
```

Then do an insert where the employee don't exist in the master table.

```
INSERT INTO MYEMPLOYEE ME
  SELECT * 
  FROM EMPLOYEE E 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MYEMPLOEE ME ON E.EMPNO=ME.EMPNO
  WHERE ME.EMPNO IS NULL;
```

If you need to do in one full sweep you can use the `IMPORT` command. But then you are dealing with files. You would need to export the EMPLOYEE table (probably with salary already formatted) and then import using the `INSERT_REPLACE` ability.

Answer (score 0):

After trying I noticed that the INSERT code should actually be like this:
1) Don't use the Name ME twice
2) Select the necessary columns because after the join there are twice the column count

```sql
INSERT INTO MYEMPLOYEE (
    SELECT E.EMPNO, E.FIRSTNME, E.MIDINIT, E.LASTNAME, E.WORKDEPT, E.PHONENO, E.HIREDATE, E.JOB, E.EDLEVEL, E.SEX, E.BIRTHDATE, E.SALARY, E.BONUS, E.COMM 
    FROM EMPLOYEE E LEFT OUTER JOIN MYEMPLOYEE ME ON E.EMPNO = ME.EMPNO WHERE ME.EMPNO IS NULL
);
```